# change border of selectbox on focus while using bootstrap silviomoreto selectbox

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, bootstrap-select

I am using bootstrap selectbox silviomoreto plugin to design selectbox. This selectbox shown red border to selectbox on pressing submit button if any option is not selected.

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker('setStyle', 'error-border','add');
```

Now i want to remove border from selectbox when user focus on it after getting an error. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.selectpicker').click(function(){ 
    if($(this).hasClass(error-border)){
        $(this).removeClass(error-border)
    }
});
```

**Working Demo**

```js
$('.selectpicker').click(function(){ 
    if($(this).hasClass('error-border')){
        $(this).removeClass('error-border')
    }
});
```

```css
.error-border{
  border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="selectpicker error-border">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```